# Проверка переменной на число в диапазоне

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Пользователь вводит номер порта, который пишется в переменную PORT, можете объяснить как сделать проверку переменной на число и причём чтобы это число было в диапазоне от 0 до 65536

Такой вариант не работает - в цикл не заходит если я в PORT пишу число больше чем 65536

```
while $PORT <= 0 || $PORT >= 65536
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в программе *bash* лучше воспользоваться арифметическими вычислениями:

```
while ((PORT<=0 || PORT>=65536))
```

если же требуется posix-совместимость, то лучше так:

```
while [ "$PORT" -le 0 -o "$PORT" -ge 65536 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Может такой вариант - `while $PORT >= 0 && $PORT <= 65536` ?